# Pass properties from array to a new class

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, class

i am working with a .net application where i have a web service that returns values in array form and now this array values i want to pass to a class and also as a reference to a private object. But since i am fresh new in programming i do not know how where an with what logic to start.
This is the private obj i created and i want to pass those references where CT is the array type and clsIn is the info that comes from another class but i have no idea how to pass neither of them.

```
  private object TotInfo(clsIn In, CT ct)
    { 
        TotInfo objFromCD = new TotInfo();

        return objFromCD;

    }
```

And here is the new class i have created that where i want to pass all the values from clsIn and CT:

```
 public class TotInfo
{        
    // Object properties
    private string LAST_OFFER;
    private string LAST_OFFER_DATE;
    private string CLOSING_REASON;

    private string _NO;
    private string _STATUS;


    #region "GET/SET Property"

    public string NO
    {
        get { return _NO; }
        set { _NO = value; }
    }
    public string LAST_OFFER
    {
        get { return _LAST_OFFER; }
        set { _LAST_OFFER = value; }
    }
    public string LAST_OFFER_DATE
    {
        get { return _LAST_OFFER_DATE; }
        set { _LAST_OFFER_DATE = value; }
    }
    public string CLOSING_REASON
    {
        get { return _CLOSING_REASON; }
        set { _CLOSING_REASON = value; }
    }
    public string STATUS
    {
        get { return _STATUS; }
        set { _STATUS = value; }
    }
    #endregion


            #region "Costruttori"
    public CardsTotInfo() { }

    public CardsTotInfo(string No, string lastOffer, string lastOfferDate, string closingReason, string status)
    {

            this.NO = No;

            this.LAST_OFFER = lastOffer.ToUpper();
            this.LAST_OFFER_DATE = lastOfferDate.ToUpper();
            this.CLOSING_REASON = closingReason.ToUpper();

             this.STATUS = status.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

I have passed, or better say i think i have passed in the correct way the values of clsIn but i do not know how to pass the properties of the array type CT[]. 
I really need help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don´t understand your question at all. You have to create an instance of `cslIn` and `CT` (horrible class-names btw.) before you´re calling the **method** `TotInf`. That method **creates** an object based on what you´ve passed to it. But in your case - as you´re doing nothing with the both variables - you can completely omit them from that method. Anyway: **where** do you call that method?

Comment: I suppose you´re problems come from the fact that you have a **method** that has the same name as your **class*, which is a quite bad idea. Instead name your *method*  someling like `CreateTotInfo`, which makes it far easier to understand what exactly you mean.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The idea is a have this CT array that return data from my web service, and for every element returned from this WS i have to go and get some other info in a database. Than both the WS and DB info that is returned as class type i should display in a grid. So at some point i have to merge this values. I thought creating a class that will have all the properties comming from this 2 sources and creating a new obj that will have this sources as parameter and after that using this object as a datasource for the grid would solve my issue. if my logic is wrong please correct me.

Comment: @HimBromBeere i am calling the method TotInf in the onNeed_data_source of my grid after getting the info i need from the WS and DB

Answer (score 0):

If CT is an object array and the data you get from the web service always comes in the same order, for instance using an arbitrary example:

`object[] CT = { 1, DateTime.Now, "foo", true }`

If you know that each property data inside the array will always be at the same index (you will always have a `int` in index 0 representing an Id, and a `DateTime` on index 1 representing the last offer day and so on)

I would say you need to set each property "manually":

```
 private object TotInfo(clsIn In, CT ct)
    { 
        TotInfo objFromCD = new TotInfo();

        //get data from DB

        //set the data from the array into the class properties
        objFromCD.Id = (int)ct[0];
        objFromCD.LastOfferDate = (DateTime)ct[1];
        objFromCD.ClosingReason = (string)ct[2];
        objFromCD.Available = (bool)ct[3];

        return objFromCD;

    }
```